# using angularjs http-auth with $resource

Tags: http, authentication, angularjs, http-authentication

I am trying to make [HTTP Auth Interceptor](https://github.com/witoldsz/angular-http-auth) Module work together with $resource.

for now, i have a basic app working with services like this :

```
angular.module('myApp.services', ['ngResource']).
factory('User', function($resource){
    return $resource('path/to/json/', {}, { 'login': { method: 'GET' } });
});
```

and then controllers like this one :

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', []).
controller('User', ['$scope', 'User', function($scope, List) 
    {    $scope.user = User.query();
]);
```

and the app :

```
angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.services', 'myApp.directives', 'myApp.controllers']).
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/dashboard', {templateUrl: 'partials/dashboard.html', controller: 'Dashboard'});
    $routeProvider.when('/user', {templateUrl: 'partials/user.html', controller: 'TrackingCtrl'});
    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/dashboard'});
}]);
```

Until now, everything is working like expected. Then, i put an http auth on the server, so the json files http status are 401 and the browser display a login popup. I would like to use the HTTP Auth Interceptor Module to replace the browser login popup and handle the login. it is the purpose of this script, right ?

To do so, i am trying to understand the [demo of the script](http://witoldsz.github.io/angular-http-auth/) and make that work with my app.

first, i injected `'http-auth-interceptor'` to the app.

then, this was added to index.html

```
<body ng-controller="UserCtrl" class="auth-demo-application waiting-for-angular">
```

and the login form above ng-view:

```
<div id="login-holder">
    <div id="loginbox">
        <div id="login-inner" ng:controller="LoginController">
             <form ng-submit="submit()">
                  Username: <input type="text" class="login-inp" ng-model="username"/><br/>
                  Password: <input type="password" class="login-inp" ng-model="password"/><br/>
                  <input type="submit" class="submit-login"/>
             </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the script at the bottom of the page:

```
<script src="lib/directives/http-auth-interceptor.js"></script>
```

in controller.js :

```
    controller('LoginController', ['$scope', 'authService', 'User', function ($scope, authService, User) {
    $scope.submit = function() {
        User.login( 
            function(user, response) { // success
                authService.loginConfirmed();
                console.log('login confirmed');
            }
        ); 
    }
}])
```

and this directive too :

```
directive('authDemoApplication', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            //once Angular is started, remove class:
            elem.removeClass('waiting-for-angular');

            var login = elem.find('#login-holder');
            var main = elem.find('#content');

            login.hide();

            scope.$on('event:auth-loginRequired', function() {
                login.slideDown('slow', function() {
                    main.hide();
                });
            });
            scope.$on('event:auth-loginConfirmed', function() {
                main.show();
                login.slideUp();
            });
        }
    }
})
```

Ok… that's it. but it's not working at all: the browser loggin form is still there. and that's the only way to login.

any idea on what i should do to make this work ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From their webpage:

#### Typical use case:

- somewhere the: **$http(...).then(function(response) { do-something-with-response })** is invoked,
- the response of that requests is a HTTP 401,
- 'http-auth-interceptor' captures the initial request and broadcasts 'event:auth-loginRequired',
- your application intercepts this to e.g. show a login dialog (or whatever else),
- once your application figures out the authentication is OK, you are to call: **authService.loginConfirmed()**,
- your initial failed request will now be retried and finally, the **do-something-with-response** will fire.

So the only thing you need to do to interact with this is to have a parent scope to listen to `even:auth-loginRequired`. This can be done in a directive, in a controller, it doesn't matter. I haven't used the software, but I'm imagining something like this:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.service('api', function(httpAutenticationService, $rootScope, $location) {
  $rootScope.$on('event:auth-loginRequired', function() {
    // For the sake of this example, let's say we redirect the user to a login page
    $location.path('/login')
  })
  $http.get(API_URL).then( ... ); // If the user is not authenticated, this will be intercepted (1)
})
.controller('LoginController', function(httpAutenticationService) {
  // Let's imagine you have a route with the 'controller' option to this controller
  $http.get(LOGIN_URL).then(function() {
    httpAutenticationService.loginConfirmed(); // The success callback from (1) will be executed now
  }, function(){
    alert("Invalid credentials")
  })
})
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. but this solution is using `$http` and i am not sure sure to understand how this interact with `$resource` and the app structure i described above. what do you think ?

Comment: You can use `$resource`, it doesn't matter. To my point is that the only thing you need is to have some scope listening to the event `event:auth-loginRequired`. If you want to use it in a directive (you would need to use the scope variable in the linking process (e.g. `var linkFn = function(scope, element, attrs) { scope.$on(...)}`. Be wary, a controller executes before the linking process, so unless you do the request through a directive, your listener might be off.

Comment: sorry for my late answer, but… hmmm… i am still confused about that. from the example file : `$http.post('data/protected', $scope.restrictedData).success(function(response) {
        // this piece of code will not be executed until user is authenticated
        $scope.restrictedContent.push(response);
      });` From what i understand, this script could work with $resource (as it depends on $http) but the result has to pass in the success callback of each $resource method. or am i missing the point ?

Comment: Yes, that would be correct. If you get a 401 response from the server, the success callback from `$resource` or `$http` gets *somehow* stored and then executed when/if the user authenticates.

Comment: ok. i updated my post above with some modifications. but it's still not working. It's like nothing was intercepted… the browser native popup is always here and working, but my login form is doing nothing.

Comment: Does the line `console.log('login confirmed');` runs?

Comment: it runs when i fill the native form of the browser, not the form inside the page. i just tried with an $http request and it has the same behavior. i added some console.log inside the interceptor and they are not running. still investigating on where i am bugging.

Comment: What about on the directive, can you try doing some `console.log` inside the `$on` functions?

Comment: finally, the problem is solved: the browser native popup was displayed because the server was sending http headers setted to `WWW-authenticate` instead of `HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized`. everything works fine now. thanks a lot for your help